# Macアプリはどうやってトライアル期限切れを知るのか？

Tags: swift, macos, apple

Macで、App Storeからでないアプリをトライアルして、トライアル期限が切れるまで使います。それから、完全に取り除いたとしても、再インストールする時トライアル期限が切れたと検出できます。アプリはどうやって知るのですか？

Comment: それがわかってしまうと何回でもトライアル期間を延ばすことができたりするので、わからないようになっています。基本的にはどこかに隠しファイルがあるのだと思います。

Answer (score 2):

いろいろな方法はあると思いますが、隠しファイルがなければ初回起動日時を記述して作成。ファイルが存在すれば、ファイルに書かれた初回起動日時から今回の起動時間までの経過時間を計算するという方法だと思います。その隠しファイルがどんな名前で何処にあるか?はそれこそアプリに依るので一概には言えません。

Answer (score 0):

アプリによって色々なのでしょうねぇ。
Dash.appというアプリでは、下記のフォルダにそれっぽいファイルがあります。

```sh
#ls        [/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/Dash/License]
license.dash-license
```